# Sanitizing sentence in PHP with preg_replace

Tags: php, regex, string, preg-replace, sanitize

This is my current sentence sanitizing function:

```
# sanitize sentence
function sanitize_sentence($string) {
    $string = preg_replace("/(?<!\d)[.,!?](?!\d)/", '$0 ', $string); # word,word. > word, word.
    $string = preg_replace("/(^\s+)|(\s+$)/us", "", preg_replace('!\s+!', ' ', $string)); # " hello    hello " > "hello hello"
    return $string;
}
```

Running some tests with this string:

```
$string = '     Helloooooo my frieeend!!!What are you doing??    Tell me what you like...........,please. ';
```

The result is:

```
echo sanitize_sentence($string);  
Helloooooo my frieeend! ! ! What are you doing? ? Tell me what you like. . . . . . . . . . . , please.
```

As you can see, I already managed to resolve some of the requirements, but i'm still stuck with some details. The final result **should be**:

```
Helloo my frieend! What are you doing? Tell me what you like..., please.
```

Which means, that all these requirements should be accomplished:

1. There can be only one or three consecutive periods **.** or **...**
2. There can be only one consecutive comma **,**
3. There can be only one consecutive question mark **?**
4. There can be only one consecutive exclamation mark **!**
5. A letter cannot repeat itself more than 2 times in a word. E.g.: **mass** (right), **masss** (wrong, and should be converted to **mass**)
6. A space should be added always after these characters **.,!?** **This is already working fine!**
7. In the case of 3 consecutive periods, the space is added only after the last period.
8. Extra spaces (more than one space) should be eliminated and trimmed form both ends of the sentences. **This is already working fine!**

Comment: So what is your question?

Comment: So your result with those rules will be the following: `Helloo my frieend! What are you doing? Tell me what you like..., please.` <- notice the helloo and frieend...

Comment: @RichardBernards yes (fixed the final string). It can't be bullet proof, so the final string would have hell**oo** and fri**ee**nd

Comment: This seems like a much more complex set of requirements than one would want to enforce via regex. Almost sounds like you would need to build your own parser for such a thing.

Comment: @MikeBrant as I understand, it can be done with an array of separated rules passed to the preg_replace() function.

Comment: @andufo Perhaps it could but you might eventually end up with hundreds of rules to more closely approximate good written form.  And who is to say that a modification to the string made by one rule is going to play nicely with other rules?  You will likely end up with an unwieldy mess of regular expressions.

Comment: Is what you are trying to do somehow different to spelling and grammar checking?

Comment: @Flosculus its strictly space and marks formatting, so that it looks nice and avoids typical human input error.

Comment: I was thinking you might benefit from integrating with something like LanguageTool.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think regex is a very appropriate technology for this. It's sanitisation, after all. Not grammer or syntax correction.

```
function sanitize_sentence($i) {

    $o = $i;

    //  There can be only one or three consecutive periods . or ...
    $o = preg_replace('/\.{4,}/','… ',$o);
    $o = preg_replace('/\.{2}/','. ',$o);

    //  There can be only one consecutive ","
    $o = preg_replace('/,+/',', ',$o);

    //  There can be only one consecutive "!"
    $o = preg_replace('/\!+/','! ',$o);

    //  There can be only one consecutive "?"
    $o = preg_replace('/\?+/','? ',$o);  

    //  we just preemptively added a bunch of spaces.
    //  Let's remove any spaces between punctuation marks we may have added
    $o = preg_replace('/([^\s\w])\s+([^\s\w])/', '$1$2', $o);

    //  A letter cannot repeat itself more than 2 times in a word
    $o = preg_replace('/(\w)\1{2,}/','$1$1',$o);

    //  Extra spaces should be eliminated
    $o = preg_replace('/\s+/', ' ', $o);
    $o = trim($o);

    // we want three literal periods, not an ellipsis char
    $o = str_replace('…','...',$o);

    return $o;
}
```

Comment: You may want to check that ',!?' don't already have spaces after them in the search so it replaces it with that singular space: preg_replace('/,+ */',', ',$o)

Comment: note that this script converts 3 or more periods to an [ellipsis character](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2026/index.htm), not 3 periods. You would need to refactor slightly if you wanted to keep those as periods

Comment: @OnlineCop that was on purpose to accommodate OPs requirement #6. My code includes a clause that tries to correct any unwanted spaces between punctuation marks

Comment: @sean9999 i noticed that, i'm trying to adapt it to convert the ellipsis to three periods. besides that issue, this looks like the working answer. Perhaps replacing the ellipsis for 3 periods at the end?

Comment: yep! that sounds like the way :) i will update the code

Answer (score 1):

I think I'll answer the questions one at a time, since it makes more sense to focus on a single task at a time instead of munging them all together.

For #5, I suggest `([a-z])(\1{0,1})\1*` replaced with `$1$2` as seen [in this example](http://regex101.com/r/tK0oQ4/1).

It takes the input

```
     Helloooooo my frieeend!!!What are you doing??    Tell me what you like...........,please.
```

and produces output

```
     Helloo my frieend!!!What are you doing??    Tell me what you like...........,please.
```

Comment: Funny, it works on the regex101 site, but not on my apache server with php 5.4.4 - for some reason it is not recognizing the **g** modifier, which is also not available in http://php.net/manual/es/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php

Comment: The 'g' modifier only adds an extra field to preg_replace: from 'preg_replace(...)' to 'preg_replace(..., 1)'. On the regex101 site, click "code generator" on the left to see the code difference.

Answer (score 0):

For #1 (**.** or **...**), `(?<!\.)(\.{3}|\.)\.*\s*` can be replaced with `$1` (note the trailing space) as can seen in [this example](http://regex101.com/r/oT3kH3/2).

This takes

```
     Helloooooo my frieeend!!!What are you doing??    Tell me what you like...........,please.
```

and produces the output

```
     Helloooooo my frieeend!!!What are you doing??    Tell me what you like... ,please.
```

As you can see, you'll get a funky `... ,` character, which is one more thing you may need to check for. You can check for the occurrence of `.,` before you do this cleanup or `. ,` (space between) afterward, unless you have another rule that you wish to utilize to remove multiple punctuation occurrences.

The generated code for this, from the regex101.com site, is the following:

```
$re = "/(?<!\\.)(\\.{3}|\\.)\\.*\\s*/"; 
$str = "     Helloooooo my frieeend!!!What are you doing??    Tell me what you like...........,please. "; 
$subst = "$1 "; 
$result = preg_replace($re, $subst, $str);
```

Answer (score 0):

For #2, #3 and #4, you can search for `([,?!])\1+\s*` and replace with `$1` (note the space afterward) as in [this example](http://regex101.com/r/cG9uW2/1).

This takes

```
     Helloooooo my frieeend!!!What are you doing??    Tell me what you like...........,please.
```

and produces

```
     Helloooooo my frieeend! What are you doing? Tell me what you like...........,please.
```

The generated code would look like:

```
$re = "/([,?!])\\1+\\s*/"; 
$str = "     Helloooooo my frieeend!!!What are you doing??    Tell me what you like...........,please. "; 
$subst = "$1 "; 
$result = preg_replace($re, $subst, $str);
```